# SharePoint variation problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When I Click on upgrade to target site this exception is shown in log file 'AzureContainerSourceUri' attribute is not declared. Any one help me to solve this?

> DeploymentWrapper::CreateVariantItems() on sourceList = 'XXX',
>   targetWeb = 'XXXX6/sites/t2/ar-ae' catches an unexpected exception:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document
>   (2, 248). ---> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: The
>   'AzureContainerSourceUri' attribute is not declared.    at
>   System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(XmlSchemaValidationException
>   e, XmlSeverityType severity)     at
>   System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(String code,
>   String arg)     at
>   System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ValidateAttribute(String lName,
>   String ns, XmlValueGetter attributeValueGetter, String
>   attributeStringValue, XmlSchemaInfo schemaInfo)     at
>   System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ValidateAttribute(StringlocalName,
>   String namespaceUri, XmlValueGetter attributeValue, XmlSchemaInfo
>   schemaInfo)     at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ValidateAttributes()
>   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessElementEvent()     at
>   System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()     at
>   System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()     at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSPExportSettings.Read11_ExportSettings()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.DeserializeExportSettings()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.DeploymentWrapper.CreateVariantItems(PublishingWeb
>   parentArea, PublishingWeb targetAreaArgument, SPList sourceList,
>   SPList targetListArgument, SPListItemCollection sourceItemBatch,
>   Boolean enforceMajorVersion, CachedVariationSettings
>   variationSettings, VariationLabel targetLabel, Hashtable
>   pageLayoutTable, Dictionary`2 availableLayoutDict, IVariationsLog
>   lroLogger, List`1 errors).

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried SharePoint variations fixup tool? 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2011/11/28/sharepoint-variations-the-complete-guide-part-11-variations-fixup-tool/